# Closed form for this sum?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

$$\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\frac{{\left({H}_{m}^{(1)}\right)}^{2} - {H}_{m}^{(2)}}{{(m+1)}^{6}}}$$

where $ \displaystyle {{H}_{k}}^{(r)} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}{\frac{1}{{i}^{r}}} $

I have no idea how to approach to this problem. I want a full closed form and an idea about how to approach these types of problems(use contour integration? I don't know, I haven't tried).

Edit: I would like to have the answer in terms of zeta function.

Comment: One method.  Compute many decimals, then put them in ISC to see if they are recognized.  http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recalling the definition of [Euler's sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html) $$s_{h}\left(m,n\right)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{H_{k}^{m}}{\left(k+1\right)^{n}}
 $$ $$\sigma_{h}\left(m,n\right)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{H_{k}^{\left(m\right)}}{\left(k+1\right)^{n}}
 $$ and using the fact that $H_{0}=0
 $ $$\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{H_{m}^{2}-H_{m}^{\left(2\right)}}{\left(m+1\right)^{6}}=\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{H_{m}^{2}-H_{m}^{\left(2\right)}}{\left(m+1\right)^{6}}=s_{h}\left(2,6\right)-\sigma_{h}\left(2,6\right)
 $$ and they can be write in terms of not so nice combinations of zeta function (see for example [here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf) and [here](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/db90/pdfs/db90-107.00.pdf)). Using the identity $22$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html), we have explicitly $$\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{H_{m}^{2}-H_{m}^{\left(2\right)}}{\left(m+1\right)^{6}}=s_{h}\left(2,6\right)-\sigma_{h}\left(2,6\right)=14\zeta\left(8\right)+\zeta\left(2\right)\zeta\left(6\right)-3\sum_{k=0}^{4}\zeta\left(6-k\right)\zeta\left(k+2\right)+
 $$ $$+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=2}^{4}\zeta\left(6-k\right)\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\zeta\left(j+1\right)\zeta\left(k+1-j\right).
 $$

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. But, it would be nicer of you if you provide with the "not so nice combinations of zeta function".

Comment: @KartikSharma I wrote the result.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Actually, I wanted to find the following - $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{120} \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{{log}^{2}(1-{e}^{-x}){x}^{5}}{{e}^{x}-1} dx} $ and I believe that they both have the same values. So, is it true?

Comment: Can you please help with this? I am asking so because the answer of the above integral was a very simple zeta function combination(I don't know the exact answer, just that it was a simple combination), so I doubt what I have done.

Comment: @KartikSharma  The series I get from the integral is $$\sum_{n\geq1}H_{n}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k\left(k+n\right)^{6}}$$ (hoping there is no mistakes :D ) which can be rewritten as $$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^{6}}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{H_{n}}{m-n}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{m}^{2}-H_{m}^{\left(2\right)}}{\left(m+1\right)^{6}}$$ so I think your calculation are right.

Comment: Thanks for that! Finally, I used your given form for ${s}_{h}(2,6) - {\sigma}_{h}(2,6)$ and then multiplied by $120$, so this is what I end up for the answer of the integral - $ \displaystyle  20{\pi}^{2}{\zeta(3)}^{2} - 720\zeta(3)\zeta(5) + 121{\pi}^{2}\zeta(6) $. Is it correct? @Marco Cantarini

Comment: @KartikSharma Numerically it doesn't match. Probably from my form there are some manipulations to get something nicer.

Comment: Yep. That was wrong! Probably some silly mistake. This is the final answer - $$ 20{\pi}^{2}{\zeta(3)}^{2} - 720\zeta(3)\zeta(5) + 61{\pi}^{2}\zeta(6)$$

Comment: @KartikSharma However you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Done! It was really helpful.