# Compute this integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$$ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{{\log}^{2}(1-{e}^{-x}){x}^{5}}{{e}^{x}-1} dx} $$

What I have done -

$ \displaystyle I(k) =  \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{{x}^{5}}{{e}^{x}{(1-{e}^{-x})}^{k}}}$

And then, $ I''(1) $ will be our integral.

Now, we need to compute $ I(k) $

$ \displaystyle I(k) = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\binom{k+m-1}{m} {e}^{-(m+1)x}{x}^{5}}} $

$ \displaystyle I(k) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\binom{k+m-1}{m} \frac{\Gamma(6)}{{(m+1)}^{6}}} $

Now, I computed

$ \displaystyle I''(1) = 120 \left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\frac{{({H}_{m}^{(1)})}^{2} - {H}_{m}^{(2)}}{{(m+1)}^{6}}}\right)$

Or, in style,

$ \displaystyle 120\left({s}_{h}(2,6) - {\sigma}_{h}(2,6)\right) $

I want to ask if the above computation is correct or not.

**EDIT** I am updating the answer now.

We can go by solving Euler sums from formula [22](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html) as was suggested by [Marco Cantarini](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/186170/marco-cantarini) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366477/closed-form-for-this-sum)
and get the form as given by Marco(watch out his answer).

Then, his form can be expanded by hand as -

$ 14\zeta(8) - 5\zeta(6)\zeta(2) - 6\zeta(5)\zeta(3) - 3{\zeta(4)}^{2} + \zeta(4){\zeta(2)}^{2} + {\zeta(3)}^{2}\zeta(2) $

which on simplification gives a really nice form -

$$ 20{\pi}^{2}{\zeta(3)}^{2} - 720\zeta(3)\zeta(5) + 61{\pi}^{2}\zeta(6) $$

Comment: @GohP.iHan: the OP is considering the second derivative with respect to the $k$ variable. Computations look fine to me.

Comment: Oh my bad, thanks! I was drunk reading this

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can I say $ \displaystyle  20{\pi}^{2}{\zeta(3)}^{2} - 720\zeta(3)\zeta(5) + 121{\pi}^{2}\zeta(6) $ is the answer?

Comment: @KartikSharma: I have not computed that Euler sums, but maybe you can add your work about them. It looks reasonable, at least.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Done. That's the answer(I have updated it).

Comment: $\frac{61}{945}\pi^8+20\pi^2(\zeta(3))^2-720\zeta(3)\zeta(5) $

Answer (score 2):

You can write $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2(1-e^{-x})x^5}{e^{x}-1}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left[\log^2(e^{x}-1)-\log^2(e^{x})\right]x^5}{e^{x}-1}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left[\log^2(e^{x}-1)-x^2\right]x^5}{e^{x}-1}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2(e^{x}-1)x^5}{e^{x}-1}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^7}{e^{x}-1}dx:=I_1-I_2.$$
Now, for $I_1,$ put $y=e^{x}-1$ then $x=\log(y+1)$ and  $dx= \frac{dy}{y+1}$ and therefore 
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2(y)}{y} \times \frac{\log^5(y+1)}{(y+1)} dy$$ and $$I_2=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(y+1)^7}{y(y+1)}dy.$$ Then 
$$I_1-I_2=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^5(y+1)\left[\log^2(y)-\log^2(y+1)\right]}{y(y+1)}dy.$$ Then remark that $\frac{1}{y(y+1)}=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y+1}.$

Comment: Can I say $ \displaystyle  20{\pi}^{2}{\zeta(3)}^{2} - 720\zeta(3)\zeta(5) + 121{\pi}^{2}\zeta(6) $ is the answer?

Comment: @KartikSharma probably it is correct using this integral formula for the Riemann zeta function : For $\Re(s)>1,$ $$\zeta(s)= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1} dt. $$

Comment: Maybe but the bottom line is that it was wrong. I have updated the answer now.